# PostgreSQL: top n entries per item in same table

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

```
| uId |   title   |  amount  |  makers  |  widgets  |
   1     richard      998       xcorp     sprocket
   2     swiss        995       ycorp     framitz
   3     ricky         90       zcorp     flobber
   4     ricky2       798       xcorp     framitz
   1     lilrick      390       xcorp     sprocket
   1     brie         200       mcorp     gullywok
   1     richard      190       rcorp     flumitz
   1     brie         490       bcorp     sprocket
```

etc...

I am trying to retrieve only 3 records per `makers`, the top 3 `amounts` and the `widgets` they produced

Here's is what I have:

```
SELECT amount, makers FROM (SELECT amount, makers, (SELECT count(*) FROM  entry  as t2
WHERE t2.amount = t1.amount and t2.makers >= t1.makers) AS RowNum
FROM entry as t1
) t3
WHERE t3.RowNum<4 order by amount;
```

Is this returning what I actually need? Is there a better way to go about this? Most of the ways I have seen to do this kind of thing are doing joins etc on disparate tables, all the info I need is on one table.

Expected Output:

```
| uId |   title   |  amounts  |  makers  |  widgets  |
  1      richard      998        xcorp     sprocket
  41     swiss        995        xcorp     widget
  989    richard      989        xcorp     sprocket
  22     swiss        995        ycorp     framitz
  92     swiss        990        ycorp     widget
  456    swiss        895        ycorp     flobber
  344    ricky        490        zcorp     flobber
  32     tricky       480        zcorp     flobber
  13     ricky        470        zcorp     flobber
```

etc...

The order of the `makers` doesn't matter so much as getting the top 3 `amounts` for each `makers`, and the `widgets` they provided. The number of `makers` is set, there will always be `x` `makers`

Comment: Given the example data in your question, can you show the expected outout as a table?

Comment: That expected output doesn't seem to make any sense given your example data. Also, if you want help you should probably go back and accept past answers to your questions. It's both polite to acknowledge those who have helped you and also makes this website more useful when others are trying to find answers to questions that you've already asked.

Comment: did it! my oversight and thanks!

Comment: from 1 million records: I need the 3 'title' with the highest 'amount' and the 'widget' they produced, grouped by 'maker'

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1124603/grouped-limit-in-postgresql-show-the-first-n-rows-for-each-group

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM (
   SELECT uid,
          title, 
          amount, 
          maker, 
          widgets,
          rank() over (partition by maker order by amount desc) as rank
   FROM entry  
) t
WHERE rank <= 3
```

Comment: `rank()` might have gaps and duplicates and therefore the filter `rank <= 3` might return more or less than 3 rows per group. `row_number()` might be more appropriate.

Comment: You are right. Another solution would be `dense_rank()` which does not produce gaps.

Comment: im going to look these up and test for results, ill get back thx!

Comment: great solution, and simple! thanks so much! I had never used partition or rank before!

Comment: But what if `amount` will be identical for several columns? `rank()` for these columns will return same value and result set could be larger than 3 rows. `dense_rank()` will fail much more, than usual `rank()` (`rank()` will fail if we have more than 3 rows with top result in field `desc`)

Comment: @wannabe: then use `row_number()`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name can you please edit the answer to have row_number instead of rank?