# How to limit N results per `group_by` in SQLAlchemy/Postgres?

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, greatest-n-per-group

This is my SQLAlchemy query code

```
medium_contact_id_subq = (g.session.query(distinct(func.unnest(FUContact.medium_contact_id_lis))).filter(FUContact._id.in_(contact_id_lis))).subquery()
q = (g.session.query(FUMessage).
         filter(FUMessage.fu_medium_contact_id.in_(medium_contact_id_subq))
         .order_by(desc(FUMessage.timestamp_utc))
         )
```

I'd like to limit `FUMessage` grouped by `medium_contact_id` with N results.

---

As a workaround, this is my current ugly and unoptimized code:

```
    medium_contact_id_lis = (g.session.query(distinct(func.unnest(FUContact.medium_contact_id_lis))).filter(FUContact._id.in_(contact_id_lis))).all()
    q = None
    for medium_contact_id_tup in medium_contact_id_lis:
        medium_contact_id = medium_contact_id_tup[0]
        if q is None:
            q = (g.session.query(FUMessage)
                 .filter(FUMessage.fu_medium_contact_id == medium_contact_id)
                 .limit(MESSAGE_LIMIT)
                 )
        else:
            subq = (g.session.query(FUMessage)
                 .filter(FUMessage.fu_medium_contact_id == medium_contact_id)
                 .limit(MESSAGE_LIMIT)
                 )
            q = q.union(subq)
    q = q.order_by(desc(FUMessage.timestamp_utc))
```

Comment: Since the subqueries that form the union do not order before limit, your results are indeterminate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way to fetch top *N* rows per group is to use a window function such as `rank()` or `row_number()` in a subselect with required grouping and order and then filter by that in the enclosing select. For *N = 1* you could use the [DISTINCT ON ... ORDER BY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16914098/how-to-select-id-with-max-date-group-by-category-in-postgresql/16920077#16920077) combination in Postgresql.

- [PostgreSQL: top n entries per item in same table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7613785/postgresql-top-n-entries-per-item-in-same-table)
- [PostgreSQL: select top three in each group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27415706/postgresql-select-top-three-in-each-group)

Adopting that to SQLAlchemy is straightforward using function element's [`over()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.over) method to produce a window expression:

```
medium_contact_id_subq = g.session.query(
        func.unnest(FUContact.medium_contact_id_lis).distinct()).\
    filter(FUContact._id.in_(contact_id_lis)).\
    subquery()

# Perform required filtering in the subquery. Choose a suitable ordering,
# or you'll get indeterminate results.
subq = g.session.query(
        FUMessage,
        func.row_number().over(
            partition_by=FUMessage.fu_medium_contact_id,
            order_by=FUMessage.timestamp_utc).label('n')).\
    filter(FUMessage.fu_medium_contact_id.in_(medium_contact_id_subq)).\
    subquery()

fumessage_alias = aliased(FUMessage, subq)

# row_number() counts up from 1, so include rows with a row num
# less than or equal to limit
q = g.session.query(fumessage_alias).\
    filter(subq.c.n <= MESSAGE_LIMIT)
```