# How can I get 20 users and 5 articles from each user?

Tags: database, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, rdbms

`Users` can have many `Articles`.

I want to get 20 of the most recent users and for each user, 5 articles.

I was reading on http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Find_recent_activity but this seems overly complicated for my scenario. However, the query mentioned in the article is stunningly fast! So I've been told. Perhaps there is a way to incorporate some of the methodologies used in the query?

I am using Postgres 9.2

Comment: You really should try to provide some sample data and expected results, to save the hassle of  needing to dummy it up. +1 anyway for  a half-decent explanation and for mentioning your version.

Comment: Define "most recent user". Most recently created? Most recently active? Posted an article most recently?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that "most recent" user means "most recently created":

### Dummy data setup

First, generate some dummy data. I haven't bothered prettily formatting this:

```
create table users ( id serial primary key, username text not null,created_at timestamptz not null default current_timestamp );
create table articles (id serial primary key, user_id integer not null references users(id), created_at timestamptz not null default current_timestamp);
insert into users (username) values ('todd'),('bob'),('janet'),('joan'),('jim'),('jolly'),('roger'),('yarr'),('fred');
update users set created_at = current_timestamp + id * INTERVAL '1' MINUTE;
insert into articles(user_id, created_at) select u.id, x from users u cross join generate_series(current_timestamp, current_timestamp + INTERVAL '1' HOUR, INTERVAL '1' MINUTE) x;
```

### PostgreSQL 9.3beta1 and above: `LATERAL`

Now, this is one of those times where it's a pity you're not on 9.3; there you could use a lateral subquery to do all this rather nicely:

```
SELECT u.username, a.id AS article_id 
FROM (
    SELECT u1.id, u1.username 
    FROM users u1 
    ORDER BY u1.created_at DESC LIMIT 5
) u,
LATERAL (
    SELECT a1.id
    FROM articles a1 
    WHERE a1.user_id = u.id
    ORDER BY a1.created_at DESC LIMIT 5
) a;
```

See: http://www.depesz.com/2012/08/19/waiting-for-9-3-implement-sql-standard-lateral-subqueries/

However, since 9.3 isn't quite released yet, it's not surprising you aren't using it.

### PostgreSQL 9.2 and older:

With 9.2 and older you have to use another layer of subqueries to work around the lack of `LATERAL` support you're in for some ugly workarounds involving the `row_number` window function and nested subqueries. See [Grouped LIMIT in PostgreSQL: show the first N rows for each group?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1124603/398670), http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/4CD0B077.2080700@ateb.com, http://troels.arvin.dk/db/rdbms/#select-top-n

Something like:

```
WITH
last_five_users AS (
        SELECT u1.id, u1.username FROM users u1 ORDER BY u1.created_at DESC LIMIT 5
)
SELECT
        lfa.username, lfa.article_id
FROM
(
        SELECT lfive.username, lfive.id, a.id, row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY a.user_id ORDER BY created_at)
        FROM articles a
        INNER JOIN last_five_users lfive ON (a.user_id = lfive.id)
) AS lfa(username, user_id, article_id, rownum)
WHERE lfa.rownum <= 10;
```

(in this case for five users and 10 articles per user).

Efficiency will be awful if the users selected have lots of articles, because it will fetch and number *all* articles for those users, not just the first `n`, then discard most of them in the outer query.

If that's a problem you could create an SQL set returning function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION last_n_articles_for_user(user_id integer, n_articles integer)
RETURNS SETOF articles AS $$
SELECT * FROM articles WHERE articles.user_id = $1 ORDER BY created_at LIMIT $2
$$ LANGUAGE sql STABLE;
```

then use that in your main query:

```
SELECT
  o.username,
  (o.last_articles).*
FROM (
        SELECT
                u.username,
                last_n_articles_for_user(u.id, 10) AS last_articles
        FROM (
                SELECT *
                FROM users u1
                ORDER BY u1.created_at DESC
                LIMIT 5
        ) u
) AS o;
```

This is likely to perform a great deal better where there's an index on `created_at`, though not as well as the `LATERAL` approach enabled in 9.3. The extra layer of subquery is required because invoking `last_n_articles_for_user` directly with the `.*` syntax will - due to an internal PostgreSQL limitation on row-returning functions - cause it to be invoked once for each column.

Comment: Very good explanation and use of examples +1

Comment: The Lateral feature does look interesting, and thanks for mentioning the set function approach