# Distinct on Postgresql JSON data column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, postgresql-json

Trying to do distinct on a mode with rails.

```
2.1.1 :450 > u.profiles.select("profiles.*").distinct


Profile Load (0.9ms)  SELECT DISTINCT profiles.* FROM "profiles" INNER JOIN "integration_profiles" ON "profiles"."id" = "integration_profiles"."profile_id" INNER JOIN "integrations" ON "integration_profiles"."integration_id" = "integrations"."id" WHERE "integrations"."user_id" = $1  [["user_id", 2]]
PG::UndefinedFunction: ERROR:  could not identify an equality operator for type json
LINE 1: SELECT DISTINCT profiles.* FROM "profiles" INNER JOIN "integ...
                        ^
: SELECT DISTINCT profiles.* FROM "profiles" INNER JOIN "integration_profiles" ON "profiles"."id" = "integration_profiles"."profile_id" INNER JOIN "integrations" ON "integration_profiles"."integration_id" = "integrations"."id" WHERE "integrations"."user_id" = $1
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedFunction: ERROR:  could not identify an equality operator for type json
LINE 1: SELECT DISTINCT profiles.* FROM "profiles" INNER JOIN "integ...
                        ^
: SELECT DISTINCT profiles.* FROM "profiles" INNER JOIN "integration_profiles" ON "profiles"."id" = "integration_profiles"."profile_id" INNER JOIN "integrations" ON "integration_profiles"."integration_id" = "integrations"."id" WHERE "integrations"."user_id" = $1
    from /Users/mmahalwy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rack-mini-profiler-0.9.1/lib/patches/sql_patches.rb:109:in `prepare'
    from /Users/mmahalwy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rack-mini-profiler-0.9.1/lib/patches/sql_patches.rb:109:in `prepare'
    from /Users/mmahalwy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:834:in `prepare_statement'
    from /Users/mmahalwy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:795:in `exec_cache'
    from /Users/mmahalwy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:139:in `block in exec_query'
    from /Users/mmahalwy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:442:in `block in log'
    from /Users/mmahalwy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.0.4/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
    from /Users/mmahalwy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:437:in `log'
    from /Users/mmahalwy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:137:in `exec_query'
    from /Users/mmahalwy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:908:in `select'
    from /Users/mmahalwy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:32:in `select_all'
    from /Users/mmahalwy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.rb:63:in `select_all'
    from /Users/mmahalwy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/querying.rb:36:in `find_by_sql'
    from /Users/mmahalwy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/relation.rb:585:in `exec_queries'
    from /Users/mmahalwy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/association_relation.rb:15:in `exec_queries'
    from /Users/mmahalwy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/relation.rb:471:in `load'
    from /Users/mmahalwy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/relation.rb:220:in `to_a'
    from /Users/mmahalwy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/relation.rb:573:in `inspect'
    from /Users/mmahalwy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/railties-4.0.4/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:90:in `start'
    from /Users/mmahalwy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/railties-4.0.4/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
    from /Users/mmahalwy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/railties-4.0.4/lib/rails/commands.rb:62:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'2.1.1 :451 >
```

Getting an error `PG::UndefinedFunction: ERROR:  could not identify an equality operator for type json`

Converting to Hstore is not an option for me in this case. Any work arounds?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

The reason behind this, is that in PostgreSQL (up to 9.3) there is no equality operator defined for `json` (i.e. `val1::json = val2::json` will always throw this exception) -- in 9.4 there will be one for the `jsonb` type.

One workaround is, you can cast your `json` field to `text`. But that won't cover all json equalitions. f.ex. `{"a":1,"b":2}` should be equal to `{"b":2,"a":1}`, but won't be equal if casted to `text`.

Another workaround is (if you have a primary key for that table -- which should be) you can use the [`DISTINCT ON (<expressions>)` form](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-select.html#SQL-DISTINCT):

```
u.profiles.select("DISTINCT ON (profiles.id) profiles.*")
```

**Note**: One known caveat for `DISTINCT ON`:

> The DISTINCT ON expression(s) must match the leftmost ORDER BY expression(s). The ORDER BY clause will normally contain additional expression(s) that determine the desired precedence of rows within each DISTINCT ON group.

Comment: I actually ended up doing the DISTINCT ON profiles.id. That was the best solution for me

Comment: how do you cast your json as a text in a select statement?

Comment: @ionescho I'm sure you've found this by now, but `::text` should do it.

Comment: Found this question from the same error with a `union` statement. Likely trying to union destincts by default. If you don't need a distinct union, changing to `union all` takes care of it.

Answer (score 11):

Sorry I'm late on this answer, but it might help others.

As I understand your query, you're only getting possible duplicates on `profiles` because of the many-to-many join to `integrations` (which you're using to determine which `profiles` to access).

Because of that, you can use a new `GROUP BY` feature [as of 9.1](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-select.html):

> When GROUP BY is present, it is not valid for the SELECT list expressions to refer to ungrouped columns except within aggregate functions **or if the ungrouped column is functionally dependent on the grouped columns, since there would otherwise be more than one possible value to return for an ungrouped column. A functional dependency exists if the grouped columns (or a subset thereof) are the primary key of the table containing the ungrouped column.**

So in your case, you could get Ruby to create the query (sorry, I don't know the Ruby syntax you're using)...

```
SELECT profiles.* 
FROM "profiles" 
  INNER JOIN "integration_profiles" ON "profiles"."id" = "integration_profiles"."profile_id" 
  INNER JOIN "integrations" ON "integration_profiles"."integration_id" = "integrations"."id" 
WHERE "integrations"."user_id" = $1
GROUP BY "profiles"."id"
```

I only removed the `DISTINCT` from your `SELECT` clause and added the `GROUP BY`.

By referring ONLY to the `id` in the `GROUP BY`, you take advantage of that new feature because all the remaining `profiles` columns are "functionally dependent" on that id primary key.

Somehow, wonderfully that avoids the need for Postgres to do equality checks on the dependent columns (ie your `json` column in this case).

The `DISTINCT ON` solution is also great, and clearly sufficient in your case, but you can't use aggregate functions like `array_agg` with it.  You CAN with this `GROUP BY` approach.  Happy days! :)

Answer (score 6):

If you use PG 9.4 , using JSONB rather than JSON solves this problem 
Example :

```
-- JSON datatype test 

create table t1 (id int, val json);
insert into t1 (id,val) values (1,'{"name":"value"}');
insert into t1 (id,val) values (1,'{"name":"value"}');
insert into t1 (id,val) values (2,'{"key":"value"}');
select * from t1 order by id;
select distinct * from t1 order by id;

-- JSONB datatype test 

create table t2 (id int, val jsonb);
insert into t2 (id,val) values (1,'{"name":"value"}');
insert into t2 (id,val) values (1,'{"name":"value"}');
insert into t2 (id,val) values (2,'{"key":"value"}');

select * from t2 order by id;

select distinct * from t2 order by id;

Result of running the above script :

CREATE TABLE
INSERT 0 1
INSERT 0 1
INSERT 0 1
1 | {"name":"value"}
1 | {"name":"value"}
2 | {"key":"value"}

ERROR:  could not identify an equality operator for type json
LINE 1: select distinct * from t1 order by id;
                    ^
CREATE TABLE
INSERT 0 1
INSERT 0 1
INSERT 0 1
1 | {"name": "value"}
1 | {"name": "value"}
2 | {"key": "value"}

1 | {"name": "value"}
2 | {"key": "value"}
```

As you can see PG succeeded to imply DISTINCT on a JSONB column 
while it  fails on a JSON column !

Try also the following to see that actually keys in the JSONB are sorted :

```
insert into t2 values (3, '{"a":"1", "b":"2"}');
insert into t2 values (3, '{"b":"2", "a":"1"}');
select * from t2;

1 | {"name": "value"}
1 | {"name": "value"}
2 | {"key": "value"}
3 | {"a": "1", "b": "2"}
3 | {"a": "1", "b": "2"}
```

note that '{"b":"2", "a":"1"}' was inserted as '{"a":"1", "b":"2"}'
therefor PG identifies that as the same record :

```
select distinct * from t2;
3 | {"a": "1", "b": "2"}
2 | {"key": "value"}
1 | {"name": "value"}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, unfortunately postgres `json` doesn't implement equality, but `jsonb` does. So migrating `json` columns to `jsonb` and it should work okay.