# GROUP BY in Postgres - no equality for JSON data type?

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group, lateral

I have the following data in a matches table:

```
5;{"Id":1,"Teams":[{"Name":"TeamA","Players":[{"Name":"AAA"},{"Name":"BBB"}]},{"Name":"TeamB","Players":[{"Name":"CCC"},{"Name":"DDD"}]}],"TeamRank":[1,2]}
6;{"Id":2,"Teams":[{"Name":"TeamA","Players":[{"Name":"CCC"},{"Name":"BBB"}]},{"Name":"TeamB","Players":[{"Name":"AAA"},{"Name":"DDD"}]}],"TeamRank":[1,2]}
```

I want to select each last distinct Team in the table by their name. i.e. I want a query that will return:

```
6;{"Name":"TeamA","Players":[{"Name":"CCC"},{"Name":"BBB"}
6;{"Name":"TeamB","Players":[{"Name":"AAA"},{"Name":"DDD"}
```

So each team from last time that team appears in the table.
I have been using the following (from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18061451/3036134)):

```
WITH t AS (SELECT id, json_array_elements(match->'Teams') AS team FROM matches)
SELECT MAX(id) AS max_id, team FROM t GROUP BY team->'Name';
```

But this returns:

> ```
> ERROR: could not identify an equality operator for type json
> SQL state: 42883
> Character: 1680
> ```

I understand that Postgres [doesn't have equality for JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23509740/distinct-on-postgresql-json-data-column). I only need equality for the team's name (a string), the players on that team don't need to be compared.

Can anyone suggest an alternative way to do this?
For reference:

```
SELECT id, json_array_elements(match->'Teams') AS team FROM matches
```

returns:

```
5;"{"Name":"TeamA","Players":[{"Name":"AAA"},{"Name":"BBB"}]}"
5;"{"Name":"TeamB","Players":[{"Name":"CCC"},{"Name":"DDD"}]}"
6;"{"Name":"TeamA","Players":[{"Name":"CCC"},{"Name":"BBB"}]}"
6;"{"Name":"TeamB","Players":[{"Name":"AAA"},{"Name":"DDD"}]}"
```

**EDIT**: I cast to `text` and following [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19723716/3036134), I used `DISTINCT ON` instead of `GROUP BY`. Here's my full query:

```
WITH t AS (SELECT id, json_array_elements(match->'Teams') AS team
           FROM matches ORDER BY id DESC)
SELECT DISTINCT ON (team->>'Name') id, team FROM t;
```

Returns what I wanted above. Does anyone have a better solution?

Comment: Try casting `team->'Name'` to `text`

Comment: It should be obvious to provide your version of Postgres. Important for the best answer. Table definition would also be useful.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Shorter, faster and more elegant with a `LATERAL` join:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (t.team->>'Name') t.team
FROM   matches m, json_array_elements(m.match->'Teams') t(team);
ORDER  BY t.team->>'Name', m.id DESC;  -- to get the "last"
```

If you just want distinct teams, the `ORDER BY` can go. Related:

- [Query for element of array in JSON column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19568123/query-for-element-of-array-in-json-column/19868697#19868697)
- [Query for array elements inside JSON type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22736742/query-for-array-elements-inside-json-type/22737710#22737710)

#### JSON and equality

There is no equality operator for the `json` data type in Postgres, but there is one for `jsonb` (Postgres 9.4+):

- [How to query a json column for empty objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24292575/how-to-query-a-json-column-for-empty-objects/24296054#24296054)

Comment: Just need to change (t.team->'Name') to (t.team->>'Name'), json has no equality.

Comment: @Watson: Right, fixed.

Comment: Since jsonb has an equality operator in 9.4+, you can just cast the json column to jsonb in some cases, using `my_json_column::jsonb`