# Activerecord group count doesn't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm trying to write a query and I cannot find the right result. I have a model like this:

```
#<Ahoy::Event id: "007d74fb-6225-4cd5-a725-6e35b2e9a859", visit_id: "34713617-d6f6-4adb-b436-8029a7ea586c", user_id: 3, name: "view", properties: {"id"=>14, "delay"=>500, "action"=>"show", "resource"=>"News", "end_point"=>"news"}, time: "2016-02-12 15:13:05">
```

It's a tracker, so I have multiple resources and the same resource is tracked a lot of time if I return on the same page.

I want to know how many news the user read, so I try with:

```
Ahoy::Event.where(user_id:3).group(:properties["resource:news"]).count
```

**Update**

I'm also trying with

```
Ahoy::Event.where(user_id:3).where("properties @> (:key => :value)", :key => 'resource', :value => 'Gate').count
```

** Update 2 **
Another tentative:

```
Ahoy::Event.where(user_id:3).where("properties --> 'resource': 'Gate'").select("properties #>> 'id' as resource, count('resource')").group("resource")
```

Comment: What database type is the `properties` column?

Comment: @SimoneCarletti it's a jsonb

Comment: JSONB has a specific syntax for querying. You will have to use that. I can't recall exactly what it is, but http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30519458/group-by-in-postgres-no-equality-for-json-data-type you may have some hint. I'm not sure if you can explicitly `GROUP BY` a jsonb field value.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried on my console in psql, it worked.

Maybe you are missing the curly brackets?

```
Ahoy::Event.where(user_id:3).
  where("properties @> ({:key => :value})", :key => 'resource', :value => 'Gate').
  count
```

Comment: I notice that I do a mistake. I must group also by properties[:id] and I miss that part. I'm getting crazy with this query... I don't know how to group by properties id.