# Couldn't identify equality operator of type json[] when using UNION

Tags: json, postgresql, union

I'm trying to perform multiple queries on a single table using a `UNION` rule

I have two tables:

- project (id, name, pinned BOOLEAN)
- skills (m2m to projects)

I'm looking to first get an array of rows which have `pinned` set to `true` and fill up the remaining with the latest entries (`pinned` set to `false`)

```
SELECT
  project.id AS project_id,
  project.name AS project_name,
  array_agg(json_build_object('skill_id', project_skills.id,'name', project_skills.skill)) AS skills
from project
LEFT OUTER JOIN project_skills on project.name = project_skills.project
WHERE project.pinned = true
GROUP BY project_id,project_name

UNION

SELECT
  project.id AS project_id,
  project.name AS project_name,
  array_agg(json_build_object('skill_id', project_skills.id,'name', project_skills.skill)) AS skills
from project
LEFT OUTER JOIN project_skills on project.name = project_skills.project
WHERE project.id != 1 AND project.pinned = false
GROUP BY project_id,project_name
ORDER BY project.create_date DESC LIMIT 5
```

When performing this query , i get the below error

> ```
> ERROR:  could not identify an equality operator for type json[]
> LINE 7:   array_agg(json_build_object('skill_id', project_skills.id,...
> ```

I don't understand this error. Is it failing because its trying to compare the json columns from both results?

I'm using Postgres 9.4.

Answer (score 107, accepted):

When you use a `UNION`, the DBMS removes any duplicate rows, and in order to do so it needs to identify whether two rows are equal / identical. This in turn means looking at each column of the two rows it's comparing, and deciding if they're equal.

The error message you're seeing is where one of your columns is built using `array_agg(json_build_object(...))` which produces a value of type `json[]`, which means "array of json values". Because Postgres doesn't know how to compare two arrays of JSON values, it can't decide if your `UNION` produced duplicates.

If you don't actually care about removing duplicates, the simplest solution is to use `UNION ALL` which skips this step.

As pointed out in comments, if you *do* want to remove duplicates, you can cast the values to something which has a comparison operator defined. The most general solution is to cast to text (e.g. `some_value::text` or `CAST(some_value as text)`) but for JSON specifically you probably want [the `jsonb` type](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-json.html), which will ignore formatting when comparing.

You could cast `json` to `jsonb`, or `json[]` to `jsonb[]`, or in this example you could build `jsonb` directly with `array_agg(jsonb_build_object(...))` rather than `array_agg(json_build_object(...))`.

Comment: @Kunkka: If `UNION` is *needed* one alternative is to cast to `jsonb` (or cast the array to `jsonb[]` accordingly), for which the equality operator is defined. See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24296054/939860 or http://stackoverflow.com/a/30520760/939860. (You lose original format, though - which is typically irrelevant.)

Comment: Had same issue and I just cast the value into text using `::text` both in the group by and in the select to facilitate the comparison it complained about. Was building hierarchy of views so at a level further up, I just cast back to json when needed with `::json[]`. Using Pg 9.6.

Comment: Had the same issue using `distinct`. Didn't need it, so I just took it out.

Comment: flawless explanation @IMSoP

Answer (score 15):

Turns out all i had to do was use `UNION ALL` - i guess this ignores trying to compare `json` types across queries.

Comment: This should be a comment to IMSoP's answer.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter i actually figured out the solution before i could get the answer to this post. i just added my answer instead of deleting the post. I accepted his answer anyways though since it was more helpful than mine