# sqlalchemy - group_by with json field attribute

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I want aggregated results from my table and I want to aggregate based on an attribute in a json field.

I tried:

```
channel_raw = db.session.query(
    Chathistory2.meta_json['channel'],
    func.sum(Chathistory2.id).label('sum')
    ).filter().group_by(Chathistory2.meta_json['channel']).all()
```

Error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.ProgrammingError) could not identify an equality operator for type json
```

Is it not possible to group by an attribute from a json field?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30519458/group-by-in-postgres-no-equality-for-json-data-type

Comment: @caliph can you add a few data rows into question and expected result?