# Rails: Using distinct with where

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, distinct

I have an ActiveRecord query:

```rb
Shareholder.where(is_company: false).distinct
```

which gives me the error:

> ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedFunction: ERROR:  could not identify an equality operator for type json

The SQL query created by ActiveRecord:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT "shareholders".*
FROM "shareholders"
WHERE "shareholders"."deleted" = $1 AND "shareholders"."is_company" = $2
```

I'm a bit puzzled that this does not work. What is wrong?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23509740/distinct-on-postgresql-json-data-column

Comment: looking at your ActiveRecord: query seems like your Shareholder model is having some issue

Comment: after removing the json type column it does work. I'll look in to this

Answer (score 5):

Distinct does not work with json column, but you can try this

```
Shareholder.select("DISTINCT ON (shareholders.id) shareholders.*").where(is_company: false).distinct
```