# from each partition, select rows with N distinct values

Tags: sql, postgresql, subquery, window-functions

I have a table with three columns `x, y, z`.  I'd like to write a query that, within each `PARTITION BY x`, returns the rows containing the first `n` distinct values of `y`.

Here's a sample for `n = 2` -- the first 2 distinct values of `y` in the first partition are 1 and 2, and 4 and 5 in the second partition, so all rows with those values of `y` are included.

```
 x   y   z   included?
----------------------
 1   1   1    true
 1   1   2    true
 1   2   3    true
 1   2   4    true
 1   3   5    false
 1   3   6    false
 2   4   7    true
 2   4   8    true
 2   5   9    true
 2   5  10    true
 2   6  11    false
 2   6  12    false
```

There's a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6064141/215044) that deals with selecting `n` rows from each partition, but that doesn't deal with the distinct values part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I"m not sure what you mean by "first". SQL tables represent unordered sets.  So, I'll assume you mean "smallest".

You can do this using `dense_rank()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, dense_rank() over (partition by x order by y) as seqnum
      from atable t
     ) t
where seqnum <= 2;
```

Comment: What if I'm instead selecting from a subquery that specifies some arbitrary ordering, and want to take the first `n` of those?

Comment: @rcrogers . . . You would put the ordering into the `order by` clause.

Comment: Is there a way for the outer query to respect the inner query's ordering, without the outer query also specifying it?

Comment: @rcrogers . . . No.  If you want a result set in a particular order, then you should use an `order by` at the outermost level.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a combination of `desnse_rank` and `row_number` to eliminate the duplicates:

```
with a as (
  select
    x, y, z,
    dense_rank() over (partition by x order by y) rk,
    row_number() over (partition by x, y order by z) rn
  from
    t
) select
  x, y, z
from
  a
where
  rk <= 2 and
  rn = 1;
```

this generates the `1, 2, 4, 5`

from this you can get the desired results by joining back onto t:

```
with a as (
  select
    x, y, z,
    dense_rank() over (partition by x order by y) rk,
    row_number() over (partition by x, y order by z) rn
  from
    t
) select
  t.*
from
  t
where
  exists (
    select
      'x'
    from
      a
    where
      a.y = t.y and
      a.rk <= 2 and
      a.rn = 1
  );
```

[Example SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/ec901/2)

Although, using `exists` in this way, makes the duplicates irrelevant, so you can just do:

```
with a as (
  select
    x, y, z,
    dense_rank() over (partition by x order by y) rk
  from
    t
) select
  t.*
from
  t
where
  exists (
    select
      'x'
    from
      a
    where
      a.y = t.y and
      a.rk <= 2
  );
```

[Example SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/ec901)