# Select top three records grouping by two factors

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I am trying to identify the three records with the highest values grouped by two factors.  I realize this question is similar to this one [PostgreSQL: select top three in each group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27415706/postgresql-select-top-three-in-each-group), but I can't figure out how to generalize from this example which includes a single factor, to two factors.  I have tried searching stack overflow for an answer to this question beyond the one listed above and I can't find one, but perhaps I'm not searching for the correct terms.

Briefly, I'm connecting to a table with the following schema

```
city, country, value
```

I only have a single row per city, country combination, but I have a variable, but the number of city entries I have per country is variable.  For example, I have a few dozen cities for Canada, a hundred for the United States, but only two for Uzbekistan.

What  I want, as output is a table with the same schema, but only countaining the rows containing the highest three values for city, nested within country.  For example, if Canada has the cities and values of

```
{Canada, toronto, 100},     {Canada, vancouver, 80}, 
{Canada, montreal,112},     {Canada, calgary, 109}, 
{Canada, edmonton, 76},     {Canada, winnipeg, 73},
```

and the United States has the entries of

```
{{us, nyc, 104},     {us, chicago, 87}, 
{us, boston, 98},    {us, seattle, 105}, 
{us, sanfran, 88},   {us, minneapolis, 84}, 
{us, miami, 103},    {us, houston, 112}, 
{us, dallas, 78},    {us, tucson, 83}}
```

and Uzbekistan has the entries of

```
 {uzbekistan, qarshi, 95}, {uzbeckistan, gluiston, 101}
```

What I would like as output would be

```
Canada, Montreal, 112
Canada, Toronto, 100
Canada, Calgary, 109
us, houston, 112
us, seattle, 105
us, nyc, 103,
uzbeckistan, qarshi, 95
uzbeckistan, gluiston 101
```

I've tried the following query

```
 SELECT logincity, logincountry, VAL
 FROM
 (
 SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY logincountry, logincity ORDER BY 
 val DESC) AS Row_ID
 FROM a_table)
 WHERE Row_ID < 4 
 ORDER BY logincity
```

But I end up with more than three cities per country. 
Can someone help me out?

Thanks Stack Overflow!

Comment: Don't tag questions for Redshift with Postgres

Comment: Why not?  It seems appropriate to me to be both a redshift question (because it's running on a redshift server) and a postgres question (because the underlying architecture of redshift is a modified version of postgres);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you only need partition by logincountry

```
SELECT logincity, logincountry, VAL
FROM (
     SELECT *, 
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY logincountry 
                               ORDER BY val DESC) AS Row_ID
     FROM a_table ) T
WHERE Row_ID < 4 
ORDER BY logincity
```

TIP: You probably will realize the problem if you include the Row_id on the SELECT

```
SELECT logincity, logincountry, VAL, Row_ID
```

On your query all `Row_ID = 1`

TIP 2: Your query want top 3 cities for each country, so you only have one partition `country`. So the linked question is the right answer, top 3 of each group in this case `country`.

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate your answer and your insights.