# Select entry with second most recent date

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

So normally, if I wanted to take the most recent of each type in this table:

```
type |    date
-----------------
  A  | 2008-07-06
  B  | 2014-08-02
  A  | 2009-12-27
  A  | 2004-03-01
  B  | 2008-10-17
  B  | 2015-01-01
```

I'd do this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (type) type, date
FROM t
ORDER BY type, date DESC;
```

But what if I want to get not the most recent, but the second most recent? So:

```
type |    date
-----------------
  A  | 2008-07-06
  B  | 2014-08-02
```

Answer (score 3):

Hmm, looking at [Grouped LIMIT in PostgreSQL: show the first N rows for each group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1124603/grouped-limit-in-postgresql-show-the-first-n-rows-for-each-group), I came up with:

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT type, date, ROW_NUMBER()
  OVER (PARTITION BY type ORDER BY date DESC) AS row FROM t
  ) tmp
WHERE tmp.row=2;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use max instead of distinct,order by:

```
SELECT type,max(date) from t group by type
```

Comment: There's other stuff in the row that I want. But in any case, how do I get not the max, but the next one down from the max – not the most recent date, but the second-to-most-recent one?

Comment: for other item, you can add them in group by list. for second you need nested query. `select * from (select * from  order by .. desc limit 2) order by asc limit 1`