# Postgres: return first N rows per group for groups having a minimum countI

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregation

I copied the logic of this helpful post [Grouped LIMIT in PostgreSQL: show the first N rows for each group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1124603/grouped-limit-in-postgresql-show-the-first-n-rows-for-each-group) to get the first N rows by group, ordered by creation date. However, I'm really only interested in this for high-volume users with some minimum row count. Does this have to be done as a set of two distinct queries or can I modify my query below?

```
SELECT userid, createdat, displaydate
FROM 
     ( SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
         (PARTITION BY userid ORDER BY createdat) as r, 
          t.* FROM data t) x 
WHERE x.r <=100
```

In particular I tried the following, which led to an error:

```
SELECT userid, createdat, displaydate
FROM 
     ( SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
         (PARTITION BY userid ORDER BY createdat) as r, 
          t.* FROM data t) x 
WHERE x.r <=100
HAVING COUNT(*) > 100
```

Ideally I'd get the first 100 rows per user for those users who have at least 100 rows of data. **How can I achieve this?**

Also I suspect that a single query may not be the most efficient way to do this even if it's achievable. **What would be the 'best practice' way to do this** (with all the provisos that I'd really need to test on my own system of course)

Answer (score 2):

You can also do the count in the subquery using another window function:

```
SELECT userid, createdat, displaydate
FROM (SELECT t.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY userid ORDER BY createdat) as seqnum, 
             COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY userid) as cnt
      FROM data t
     ) x 
WHERE x.seqnum <= 100 AND x.cnt > 100;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT userid, createdat, displaydate
FROM 
     ( SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
         (PARTITION BY userid ORDER BY createdat) as r,count() OVER 
         (PARTITION BY userid) as counting
          t.* FROM data t) x 
WHERE x.r <=100 and counting > 100
```