# PostgreSQL LATERAL JOIN to LIMIT GROUP BY

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

Sorry I'm just failing to do the lateral join!

I got a table like this:

```
ID | NUMBER | VALUE
-------------------
20 | 12     | 0.7
21 | 12     | 0.8
22 | 13     | 0.8
23 | 13     | 0.7
24 | 13     | 0.9
25 | Null   | 0.9
```

Now I would like to get the first 2 rows for each NUMBER sorted by decreasing order of VALUE.

```
ID | NUMBER | VALUE
-------------------
21 | 12     | 0.8
20 | 12     | 0.7
24 | 13     | 0.9
22 | 13     | 0.8
```

The code I tried so far looks like this:
(Found: [Grouped LIMIT in PostgreSQL: show the first N rows for each group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1124603/grouped-limit-in-postgresql-show-the-first-n-rows-for-each-group/44211929#44211929))

```
SELECT DISTINCT t_outer.id, t_top.number, t_top.value
FROM table t_outer
JOIN LATERAL (
     SELECT * FROM table t_inner
    WHERE t_inner.number NOTNULL
    AND t_inner.id = t_outer.id
    AND t_inner.number = t_outer.number
    ORDER BY t_inner.value DESC
    LIMIT 2
     ) t_top ON TRUE
order by t_outer.value DESC;
```

Everything is fine so far, it just seems like the LIMIT 2 is not working. I get all the rows for all NUMBER elements back.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make use of windows analytical function `row_number`

[Rextester Demo](http://rextester.com/FBQ34164)

```
select "ID", "NUMBER", "VALUE" from 
(select t.*
 ,row_number() over (partition by "NUMBER" 
                     order by "VALUE" desc
                    ) as rno
from table1 t
) t1
where t1.rno <=2;
```

Output

```
ID  NUMBER  VALUE
21  12      0,8000
20  12      0,7000
24  13      0,9000
22  13      0,8000
25  NULL    0,9000
```

Explanation:

Inner query t1, will assing `rno` order by `value` desc for each `number` group. Then in outer query, you can select `rno <= 2` to get your output.