# Most efficient way to use aggregate functions in table join?

Tags: postgresql, left-join, aggregate-functions

I'm attempting to join two tables where all the records in table one have unique ids and table two *can* contain multiple records for an id in table one (ids in table one may not have any corresponding records in table two).

I would like to join only the most recent record in table two.

```
SELECT id, MAX(date) AS DATE FROM table_two
```

Above returns the most recent records for a particular id.

```
SELECT * FROM table_one t1 LEFT JOIN table_two t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
```

Above returns the joined table but returns the duplicates as well.

**How can I construct the join statement to return only the most recent records in table two?**

Something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table_one t1 LEFT JOIN table_two t2 ON t1.id = t2.id, MAX(t2.date) AS date GROUP BY date
```

Above returns an error: `ERROR: aggregate functions are not allowed in functions in FROM`

**I know I can use a subquery to get the most recent record but not sure of the most efficient way to do this.**

Comment: What version of postgresql? (Determins if lateral is an option or if the row_Number method should be used or if we just need to subquery.

Comment: @xQbert version is 9.5.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both of these are untested; I'll get it working if a rextester.com test case is setup.

Postgresql 9.2? and up, I think, implements an outer apply using the `lateral` keyword.  This basically runs a select against table 1 and then runs the select from table 2 for each record in table 1; returning from table 2 the newest dated record for the respective ID; but without having to do so in a loop the engine can somehow handle the join as a "SET" and thus doesn't suffer from a loop/row-by-row performance impact.

```
SELECT * 
FROM table_one t1 
LEFT JOIN LATERAL (SELECT A.*
                   FROM table_two A
                   WHERE A.ID = T1.ID
                   ORDER BY A.Date desc
                   LIMIT 1) t2 
  ON TRUE
```

[Grouped LIMIT in PostgreSQL: show the first N rows for each group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1124603/grouped-limit-in-postgresql-show-the-first-n-rows-for-each-group) for other examples.

--Should work on many prior versions since its not using analytical functions or lateral.

```
SELECT T1.*, t2.*
FROM table_one t1 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT A.* 
           FROM table_two A
           INNER JOIN (SELECT MAX(date) AS date, ID 
                       FROM table_two
                       GROUP BY ID) B
              on B.ID = A.ID
             and B.Date = A.Date) t2
 ON t1.id = t2.id
```

basic concepts of the above... get the max date and ID for a record in table 2
join this back to the base set of table2 to get all the details of a record in table2 having the max date per ID.  then join to table 1 to get t1 and t2 values.

Comment: Both queries work, I haven't used  `lateral` before. Is there a significant  performance advantage by using one over the other (vs. a more simplified subquery)?

Comment: Lateral is the newer syntax and should be more efficient as it doesn't have to generate the sub query results allowing the engine to generate a  more optimal execution plan.  I would recommend running the explain plan for both and analyze the results.  I think you'll see lateral is more efficient; but that always depends on indexes, hardware, and data volume (table statistics) that the Cost Based Optimizer (CBO) uses.

Comment: Put another way 10 years ago you'd have had to use the 2nd query.  it's about the only way you could do what you wanted in Pure SQL.  5 years ago and still today you could use a row_number logic to get the earliest date per record and then join..  today, LATERAL (CROSS/OUTER APPLY in other engines) are used to return these situations when you have a 1-N relationship and want to return x rows from the N side. the DB Manufacturers deemed this CROSS Apply approach beneficial to handle these 1-N with x rows from inside.  if they built it, it must be equal to or better than what was done before.

Comment: yep, running explain on the methods proposed here has lateral winning by a landslide. Thanks for the information!

Comment: @DonPeat take note of sagar's use of row_number prior to lateral, it ***was*** the most efficient.  it's the 3rd way I didn't bother to spell out as they already had.

Comment: sagar's queries don't return the correct results though I'm sure i could tweak them to work. The run time on row_number for this specific query is still not as fast as the group by query above.

Answer (score 2):

You have to make use of subquery.
Here are two possible answers:

Using row_number and subquery

```
select * from(
    SELECT t1.*,row_number() over(partition by t2.id order by t2.date desc) as row_num
    FROM table_one t1
    LEFT JOIN table_two t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
)t
where t.row_num = 1
```

Using max and subquery

```
SELECT * FROM table_one t1 
LEFT JOIN 
(
    SELECT id, MAX(date) AS DATE FROM table_two group by id
)t2
ON t1.id = t2.id
```

Comment: the 2nd approach here doesn't get all the column information from t2; just the max date.  may need to do a self join so all columns can be returned.

Comment: @sagar The first query doesn't seem to return all of the information from t1, the second query requires a group by in order to use the aggregate function?

Comment: yes right @DonPeat, group by id needed in second query. For first query (t1.*) should return all the columns