# How to limit number of rows by foreign key?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, relational-database

I'm writing a query in which i want to limit the number of rows by foreign key id.

To give you an example let's say i have a posts table and each post has anywhere from 0 to 100 comments.

Now right now I'm looping over all posts individually and then SELECT the comments for each post using a LIMIT 0,5.

What i want to do instead is just write one SELECT statement for reading all the comments using something like `post_id IN (1,2,3,4...999)` but only load up to 5 comments per each post?

**Edit:** The postgres way of doing it can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1124603/grouped-limit-in-postgresql-show-the-first-n-rows-for-each-group). The mysql way of doing it is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2129693/using-limit-within-group-by-to-get-n-results-per-group)

Comment: Which database are you using? In postgresql you would do this using a window function or a lateral join. Anyway, this sort of query is usually called a `top-N per group` query, if you're looking to google it.

Comment: I'm using mysql right now but if postgres supports it i would be very eager to learn it too

Comment: Would you please show your table structure? Is there any column that determines which first 5 comment should be? A comment id perhaps?

Comment: Please update your post and provide us from sample data / table structure and desired result

Comment: for postgres you use `row_number()` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1124603/grouped-limit-in-postgresql-show-the-first-n-rows-for-each-group

Comment: @FerdinandGaspar post table contains `post_id`, `date` and `title`, comments table contains `comment_id`, `post_id`, `date` and `text`. I want to  get the last 5 comments (i.e. `comments.date DESC`)

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza thanks for the links