# In PostgreSQL, How do I random sample from table based on the proportion of each level in a categorical column?

Tags: sql, postgresql, random

For example, if I have a column called `companyId` and many other columns I want to keep, and in `companyId` I have values like `100`, `101`, `102`, ..., basically a list of Ids and each Id appear different number of times. How do I randomly sample data based on the `companyId` column so that it's according to the proportion of each Id?

eg: If I have 500 rows and 100 `companyA`, 100 `companyB` and 300 `companyC` and I want to sample 100 rows from this table. How do I make my data have 20 `companyA`, 20 `companyB` and 60 `companyC`?

Comment: already answered in stackoverflow please refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1124603/grouped-limit-in-postgresql-show-the-first-n-rows-for-each-group

Answer (score 16):

You should use the `TABLESAMPLE` clause available since PostgreSQL 9.5, described in the [`SELECT` documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-select.html).

There are two built-in *table sampling methods*: `SYSTEM` and `BERNOULLI`. Both try to get a random sample, but the `SYSTEM` method picks table blocks and uses the data therein, while `BERNOULLI` uses a random sample from the whole table. `SYSTEM` is faster, but `BERNOULLI` offers a more evenly distributed sample.

You have to specify the percentage of the rows that you want to get.
If you want a fifth of your table, you would use:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable TABLESAMPLE BERNOULLI (20);
```

If your requirement is to get a certain number of result rows, you might consider using the [tsm_system_rows](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tsm-system-rows.html) contrib module, which offers the `SYSTEM_ROWS` table sample method that works similar to `SYSTEM`, but you can specify the number of result rows.

Comment: does this answer the question? The OP wants to know how to sample "20 companyA, 20 companyB and 60 companyC?"

Comment: You are right, it is an approximation. I assumed that these numbers were just for illustration and represent an estimate rather than hard requirements (note that the numbers are proportional to the frequency with which the values occur in the table).

Comment: thanks for that note, it does help understanding how tablesample works.