# SQL - LIMITing AND filtering a join at same time

Tags: sql, postgresql-9.6

I need a solution for following Problem.
I have two Tables:

```
ids from new user (got by subquery)

+------------+
|  user_id   |
+------------+
| 1          | 
| 4          | 
| 5          |
+------------+

users (table with all users)
+------------+
|  user_id   |
+------------+
| 1          | 
| 2          | 
| 3          |
| 4          |
| 5          |
| ...        |
+------------+
```

i need to join this two tables. every new user needs **exactly 3** connections to other users.

for example:

```
+----------+------+
| new_user | user |
+----------+------+
| 1        | 2    |
| 1        | 3    |
| 1        | 4    |
| 4        | 1    |
| 4        | 2    |
| 4        | 3    |
| 5        | 1    |
| 5        | 2    |
| 5        | 3    |
+----------+------+
```

the problem is to limit the entries to **exactly 3** and to exclude redundant entries (like 1|1, 3|3, ...)

Comment: sry, i forgot these. postgresql 9.6

Comment: I think Oracle 12c1+, PostgreSQL 9+, DB2 9+, SQL Server 2014+ will provide you a solution to this query. Which database and version do you have?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1124603/grouped-limit-in-postgresql-show-the-first-n-rows-for-each-group

Refer this similar question

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1124603/grouped-limit-in-postgresql-show-the-first-n-rows-for-each-group
is an other solution, but not that easy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In PostgreSQL you can use a `lateral` query to retrieve a limited number of rows in a subquery.

I don't know the exact structure of your main query or subquery but it should look like:

```
select t.*, ls.*
  from main_table t,
  lateral ( -- lateral subquery
    select * from secondary_table s
      where s.col1 = t.col2 -- filtering condition, if needed
      fetch first 3 rows only -- limit to a max of 3 rows
  ) ls;
```

The lateral subquery is executed once per every row in the `main_table`.

Comment: Thank you. Thats exactly what I was looking for. :)

Comment: Found it myself like a year ago, when I needed it badly.

Comment: The filter condition isnt `s.col1 != t.col2` ?