# Performing a batch select latest n in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql

Suppose I have query for fetching the latest 10 books for a given author like this:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM books
WHERE author_id = @author_id
ORDER BY published DESC, id
LIMIT 10
```

Now if I have a list of `n` authors I want to get the latest books for, then I can run this query `n` times. Note that `n` is reasonably small. However, this seems like an optimization opportunity.

**Is there are single query that can efficiently fetch the latest 10 books for `n` given authors?**

This query doesn't work (only fetches 10, not `n * 10` books):

```sql
SELECT *
FROM books
WHERE author_id = ANY(@author_ids)
ORDER BY published DESC, id
LIMIT 10
```

Comment: that means user wise latest 10 books u wanna fetch

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/37862028/12135804
lateral joins are a bit cryptic, but the best analogy I've heard is they're like a "foreach"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Grouped LIMIT in PostgreSQL: show the first N rows for each group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1124603/grouped-limit-in-postgresql-show-the-first-n-rows-for-each-group)

Answer (score 2):

First provided author wise book where book is serialized by recent published date for generating a number using ROW_NUMBER() and then in outer subquery add a condition for fetching the desired result.

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT *
           , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY author_id ORDER BY published DESC) row_num
      FROM books
      WHERE author_id = ANY(@author_ids)) t
WHERE t.row_num <= 10
```

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT b.*
FROM authors a
JOIN LATERAL (
  SELECT *
  FROM books b
  WHERE b.author = a.id
  ORDER BY b.published DESC, b.id
  LIMIT 10
) b ON TRUE
WHERE a.id = ANY(@author_ids)
```