# How to join two tables A and B and have the most recent status from B?

Tags: postgresql

I have two tables: A and B

A

| provider_id | date |
| --- | --- |
| 111 | date |
| 222 | date |
| 333 | date |

B

| provider_id | status | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 111 | initialized | date |
| 111 | released | date |
| 222 | failed | date |

The result I want

| provider_id | status | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 111 | released | A date |
| 222 | failed | A date |
| 333 | null | A date |

Among the things I tried is the left join

```
select * from "A" left join "B" on "B"."provider_id" = "A"."provider_id" order by "A"."date" desc;
```

But I got the duplicated records based on `status`

| provider_id | status | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 111 | initialized | date |
| 111 | released | date |
| 222 | failed | date |
| 333 | null | date |

Comment: Not certain if this is a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1124603/grouped-limit-in-postgresql-show-the-first-n-rows-for-each-group

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `distinct on` to retrieve only one record per `provider_id` and `order by` to specify that this shall be the most recent (latest) one. [More info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group/7630564#7630564)

```sql
select distinct on (provider_id)
    provider_id, status, "B"."date" 
from "A" left join "B" using (provider_id)
order by provider_id, "B"."date" desc;
```

| provider_id | status | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 111 | released | 2022-01-03 |
| 222 | failed | 2022-01-02 |
| 333 |  |  |

Answer (score 0):

To sort on the A date, you can join B with a subquery

```
select * from "A" left join (
    select distinct on ("provider_id") * from "B" order by "provider_id", "date" desc
) B using ("provider_id") order by "A"."date" desc;
```